# How to use the keyword "location" in the URL parameter in AWS Amplify

Tags: redirect, aws-amplify, url-parameters

I am currently working on a 1 page HTML app that uses URL parameters to do an API call. the URL parameters are set and used in QR codes so its necessary that they are able to change dynamically. A example URL would be something like *app.com/index.html/?environment=demo&location=Kiosk*

I currently have this app deployed in AWS Amplify, but I cant get other keywords to chain together. I have the following redirects in place:
[image]

These redirects make sure that every URL parameter I pass in the link works **EXCEPT**  some keywords like the "location" keyword, next to some others. Using this keyword as a URL param gives a *502 server error*, or if the redirects are not used an *access denied error*.

does anyone know how to get the location keyword to work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a single rule that will forward everything to index.html EXCEPT urls with a "file extension" from the list below. That lets all your links work, but assets like images, fonts, code will pass through.

Doc for: [Using Redirects - Single Page Apps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa)

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>
```